# Login form within vb.net- to direct to different forms

Tags: vb.net, oracle

In a Login form for VB.Net connected to an Oracle database.. Is there a way of inserting an If statement to direct different users to different forms.. Eg, an accountant to the accounting home page or a driver to a driver homepage even though all there ID's and passwords are in the one table within the database.

There is a POSITION field within the database and this is what I would like to use to differentiate the different users levels of access.

Here is the code working so far:

```
Dim conn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection

conn.ConnectionString = _
"Provider=msdaora;Data Source=orabis;User Id=112221800;Password=112221800;"


conn.Open()

Dim parmuser As New OleDb.OleDbParameter

parmuser.OleDbType = OleDb.OleDbType.Char

parmuser.Value = txtStaffNo.Text

Dim parmpass As New OleDb.OleDbParameter

parmpass.OleDbType = OleDb.OleDbType.Char

parmpass.Value = txtPassword.Text



Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand

cmd.Connection = conn

cmd = New OleDbCommand("select STAFFID,PASSWORD from STAFF where STAFFID ='" & txtStaffNo.Text & "' and PASSWORD ='" & txtPassword.Text & "'", conn)

cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text

Dim dr As OleDb.OleDbDataReader



dr = cmd.ExecuteReader()


If txtStaffNo.Text = "" Or txtPassword.Text = "" Then

    MessageBox.Show("You have not entered any values!", "ERROR", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)

ElseIf dr.Read() Then

    txtStaffNo.Text = dr("STAFFID")

    txtPassword.Text = dr("PASSWORD")

    MsgBox("Access Allowed")



    CustOption.Show()
    Me.Hide()

Else

    'MessageBox.Show("Wrong Username and Password", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    'intCount = intCount + 1



End If
```

Comment: Is the Position column in the STAFF table?

Comment: NOTE: you should never store and retrieve password in this way. What happens if i type in the password: aa' or '1'='1 ?

Comment: Yes the position field is in the staff table.. I dont understand what you mean about the password? that part is working so its the least of my worries..

Comment: 112221, The comment about your passowrd is related to "SQL Injection".  Your code is vunerable to hacking.  You would do well to read about and understand "SQL Injection" vulnerabilities and how to address them.

Comment: Its for a college project.. Hacking is not an issue.. Have you any idea how i could interact the Position field to navigate to different forms? there are 3 different positions, Accountant, driver and production manager?

Answer (score 0):

For a web site/app use

```
switch (position){
case "Admin":
    Server.Transfer("AdminHomePage.aspx";
    brea;
case "blabla":
//and so on
default:
    Server.Transfer("Home.aspx"

}
```

For a windows forms the answer is similar. But you have wo pick a form.
I.e. `new FormAdminHome().ShowDialog()`

Comment: IT IS A WINDOWS FORM APPLICATION?

Comment: Also very basic programming skills by myself, so detailed help would be a huge bonus.. Thanks

Comment: Yes the position field is in the staff table.. I dont understand what you mean about the password? that part is working so its the least of my worries..

Answer (score 0):

I think that you answered your own question.  Just add the POSITION to your query, then just say something like:

```
If dr("POSITION")="JANITOR" Then
    //Go to janitor site
ElseIf ...
    ...
End If
```

Like the others have said though, you really shouldn't be passing passwords around like that.  Is there actually a reason you're returning the password?  If the query even returns anything the user is "Authenticated", so why even return it?

Comment: It is only a college project and that part is working so im not worried too much about it to be honest.. thanks for your input..